# How to catch boost asio boost::system::error_code connect exception separatly from other exceptions?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio, execution

Boost asio has such [socket connect api](http://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_3_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket/connect.html). I have such simple code:

```
try
{
    std::string addr;
    std::string port;
    sscanf(tcpUrl.c_str(), "tcp://%[^:]:%d", &addr, &port);

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    tcp::resolver::query query(tcp::v4(), addr.c_str(), port.c_str());
    tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

    tcp::socket s(io_service);
    s.connect(*iterator);
    Sleep(250);
    s.close();
}
catch (std::exception& e)
{
    return -1;
}
```

All I want is to try to connect and catch boost::system::error_code connect exception. Only it. I do not need to cach any more. and on it I need to return -1. How to do such thing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
catch( const boost::system::system_error& ex )
{
  return -1;
}
```

Please catch by const reference.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?  Why const ref?

Comment: Ref because you don't want to make a copy.  Const because you don't want to change it.

Comment: I know this is old, but the exception that is thrown is actually a boost::system::system_error, not the error_code itself.

Comment: For the record, this doesn't work all the time. I think this response doesn't actually solve the issue. For me, the exception happens when closing a socket. AFAIK, this exception is just impossible to catch, your program WILL crash... only way around it is to leave the socket open.